# how to insert object in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have a class as follows:

```
package mongo;

import com.mongodb.BasicDBObject;

public class tweet extends BasicDBObject{


private String name;
private Integer id;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
 }
 }
```

Now I am trying to insert the object of this class into mongodb:

```
public void connect() throws UnknownHostException
{
        MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient( "localhost" , 27017 );
        DB db = mongoClient.getDB( "test" );
        tweet t=new tweet();
        t.setId(100);
        t.setName("Gggggg");
        DBCollection Collection = null ;
        Collection = db.getCollection("test");
        DBObject doc = new BasicDBObject();
        doc.put("first", t);
        Collection.save( doc);

        System.err.println(Collection.findOne());
}
```

But when I run this code, the object t is not inserted to the db and the `system.err.println` return the following:

```
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "546c00efbadcd42088c8fee3"}}
```

How can I add the object into mongodb? Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BasicDBObject` is actually a `LinkedHashMap`. So when you extend it, you need to `put` and `retrieve` values as you do it in a `map`.

So simply setting the values as attributes doesn't make sense, those attributes need to be put inside the `Tweet` map.

You need to modify your `Tweet` Class as follows:

```
class Tweet extends BasicDBObject{

public String getName() {
   return (String)this.get("name");
}

public void setName(String name) {
     this.put("name", name);
}

public Integer getId() {
    return (Integer)this.get("_id");
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.put("_id", id);
 }
 }
```

and your main method as:

```
    MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient( "localhost" , 27017 );
    DB db = mongoClient.getDB( "test" );
    Tweet t=new Tweet();
    t.setId(100);
    t.setName("Ghorbani");
    DBCollection collection = null ;
    collection = db.getCollection("test");
    collection.save(t);

    System.err.println(collection.findOne());
```

If you notice,`collection.save(t);`, the `Tweet` object is being directly saved. That is how it should work.

o/p:

```
{ "_id" : 100 , "name" : "Ghorbani"}
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be trying to set an ID for your object. Usually that is something that is done automatically from Mongo. Try removing `t.setId(100);` and then run your code again.

Tip - try using Mongoose to manage your connection to Mongo.

Comment: Hi, actually that id is something else and I need to insert it but even if I remove setId the same problem exists